# SharePoint workflow to conduct a keyword search within documents to populate columns

Tags: workflow

I've tried a couple ways of going about this but keep running into dead ends, so I wanted to see if anyone has done something similar to this in the past. My goal is to create a workflow that will search through any uploaded documents in a library (in this case I'm trying to search through resumes, so it isn't uniformly formatted) for specified keywords, and then auto populate a "Keyword" column in the document library. That way, the resumes could be easily filtered based on which keywords we're looking for. I know that the basic SharePoint search will search through documents and return documents that contain that keyword, but it doesn't always seem to work, and we would much rather have it in column form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not done anything like this. But you can take a look here:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Extract-data-from-documents-with-Microsoft-Flow/ba-p/370422

For a code based approach
Use an event reciever and override the itemAdded event:

1. **Note**: I have assumed that all are doc files, but if they are different files,we can write a different code for each and use a switch based on extention.
2. I have assumed, that you need to store all the keywords in a single column. You can use any kind of logic though- the basic code remains same

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (SPSite site = properties.OpenSite())
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
            var byteArray = file.OpenBinary();
            string filePath = Path.Combine("<<Path where you want to store>>", file.Name);

            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
            {
                fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
        List AvailablekeyWords= ExtractKeyWords(filePath);
            var currentItem=properties.ListItem;
            currentItem["KeyWordColumn"]=AvailablekeyWords.Join(',');
            currentItem.Update();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }
public List<String> ExtractKeyWords(string filePath){
// needs a reference to  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word; 
  List<string> keyWords=`new List<String>(){"SharePoint","O365"};
 List<string> AvailableKeyWords=`new List<String>();

   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();  
   object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  
   object path =filePath);  
   object readOnly = true;  
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);  
   
   for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)  
   {  
     var string= docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());  
    foreach(var item in keyWords){
     if(string.Contains(item))
    {
          AvailableKeyWords.Add(item);
    }
     
    }
   }   
   
   return AvailableKeyWords;
}
```

**Client side approach if you can't deploy wsp**
Add a hidden column called status (hide it from list form
using css in content editor or in SP designer-> create a item add and edit form)

By default make the status='New'

Create a windows task and schedule it to run every 1 hour (or whatever interval you want)
the windows task will call an .exe file, which will have the following code in the main function:

```
//Add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
//and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime dlls

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

Public static void Maain(string args[]){
 ClientContext context=new ClientContext("Url of the web containing the library")
 context.credentials= CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
 List ResumeLibrary=context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Title of the library");
 Caml camlQuery=new CamlQuery(){
    @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Status"/><Value Type="Text">"New"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
     };
 ListItemCollection resumes=ResumeLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);
 context.Load(resumes,r=>r.File);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var resume in resumes){
            var file=resume.File;

            var byteArray = file.OpenBinary();
            string filePath = Path.Combine("<<Path where you want to store>>", file.Name);

            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)
            {
                fs.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        
            }
            List AvailablekeyWords= ExtractKeyWords(filePath);//same method described earlier
            
            resume["KeyWordColumn"]=AvailablekeyWords.Join(',');
            resume["Status"]="Completed";
            currentItem.Update();
            contex.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

This code will execute everytime the scheduled job runs and pick all new resumes and extract the keywords. Then change the status to completed

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to connect my SharePoint site to Microsoft Flow. I think it has something to do with the way security is run.

Comment: Is a code based solution suitable to you? Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'd be willing to try a coded solution! I'm using SharePoint server 2013.

Comment: Thank you so much! Little bit of a dumb question- do I embed this in the page of the library? I haven't done too much javascript in SharePoint

Comment: Umm. Sorry . This is a server side code. You need to deploy a solution as a .wsp package in the server. Do you have permission to do that?  If not, then we need to think of an alternative solution again

Comment: I might have permission, let me do some research and try a few things and get back to you. Thank you again- this is really helpful.

Comment: Okay so it doesn't seem like I have permission to do that sadly.

Comment: do you have the permission to run a windows task in windows task scheduler in the server or your own computer (please specify if which one of the above is more suitable)? Do you have an account (either yours or a service account) which has at least contribute access to the library? Then I can give a different solution

Comment: I have permission to run a windows task on my own computer, and my account does have contribute access to the library.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems like it will work. Just a few quick questions- does the filePath string refer to a place on my personal PC that the file will be stored, or is that within the SharePoint site? Also, where do I put the list of keywords I want it to search for?

Comment: The filepath is a  path in your computer.You can make it configurable in the app settings file.The list of key words can also be a comma separated value in your app settings section of your app.config file. You can create a c# List of string by parsing it. In my code I have hardcoded them for simplicity in the line List<string> keyWords=`new List<String>(){"SharePoint","O365"};